# Call the function in parent scope within a directive does not update parent scope

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I tried to call the function in parent scope within a directive link function to update the one of parent scope attributes.

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
    var users = [{
        name: 'Andy',
        age: 9
    },{
        name: 'Tom',
        age: 10
    },{
        name: 'Jerry',
        age: 11
    },{
        name: 'Harry',
        age: 12
    }];

    $scope.users = users;
    $scope.currentUser = users[0];
    $scope.updateCurrentUser = function(index) {
        $scope.currentUser = users[index];
    };
});

app.directive('myDirective', function() {
    return {
        template: '<div><button ng-repeat="user in users">{{ user.name }}</button></div>',
        restrict: 'EA',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            element.on('click', 'button', function() {
                scope.updateCurrentUser($(this).index());
            });
        }
    };
});
```

[source code](http://jsbin.com/qunagowudetu/7/edit?html,js,output)

Suppose I click any button, the currentUser should display the update corresponding user data. however, looks like it does not work. I wonder why and how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the `click` event is handled without Angular's knowledge, you need to `$apply` your changes:

```
element.on('click', 'button', function() {   
    scope.updateCurrentUser($(this).index());
    scope.$apply();
});
```

`$apply` runs and Angular `$digest`.  The `$digest` will take care of two-way binding in the parent.

Comment: Why should the OP use $apply and a jquery event when she can just do it with the ng-click directive?

Comment: Depending on the context, some things cannot easily be done with adding attributes to the template.  So, this is a good answer to the question.  `ng-click` essentially does this underneath anyway.

Comment: Fair enough, but in this case there is a directive for that already... What I mean is that anytime that I have to integrate an external plugin in angularjs I create a directive for that, in this case there was no need, because there is a directive already created that handles the click event.

Comment: from angular wiki: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/When-to-use-$scope.$apply()

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to use a `jQuery` event, you can just use the `ngClick` directive, your code will be much cleaner and angularjs friendly:

Change your directive, make it like this:

```
app.directive('myDirective', function() {
  return {
    template: '<div><button ng-click="updateCurrentUser($index)" ng-repeat="user in users">{{ user.name }}</button></div>',
    restrict: 'EA'
  };
});
```

### [Working example](http://jsbin.com/beyugutonosu/1/edit)